# How to find what's stopping “Gnome” to load after entering credentials on login screen?

Tags: linux, boot, gnome

I've got “Pop!_OS 21.10” installed on my notebook, and it takes a couple of minutes after typing the credentials on the login page and entering gnome (During this time my display goes blank) on every boot.

I have no idea where to look for any problems? Help me to fix this, please.

Comment: Probably the video driver or OGL itself is crashing.  Check /var/log/Xorg.?.log.old (and variants) for errors (line starts with EE).  Also look at non-errors to see if OGL loaded.

Comment: OpenGL is loaded I believe because running `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` returns `OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.2.2` to me, And Errors I've found in Xorg log files are 4 of this line:

`modeset(0): failed to set mode: Permission denied` Any idea if it's ok or not @user10489?

Comment: I also completely purged `Nvidia` drivers to see it they are causing the problem, but the `black screen` is still here :(

Comment: The issue is that you need the *right* driver for your card and it will fail until it is there.

Comment: I'm running Pop-Os on Nvidia proprietary driver @user10489 What do you recommend?

Comment: Please add your card model and driver version to the question.